# Filtering using Isotope js and knockout

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-isotope, knockout-3.0

In my current project for filtering of data I was provided with a plug-in which had isotope.min.js as reference. In the HTML page there were 4 li's which acted as a filter like this

```
<ul class="filter list-inline">
    <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">Photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".illustration">illustration</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding">branding</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web-design">web design</a></li>
</ul>
```

and 10 divs like this

```
<div class="project-post illustration web-design">
  <div class="item-img-wrap ">
    <img src="img/img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="workimg">
    <div class="item-img-overlay">
      <a href="img/img-1.jpg" class="show-image">
        <span></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="work-desc">
    <h3><a href="portfolio-single.html">Logo Design</a></h3>
    <span>illustrate</span>
  </div>
  <!--work desc-->
</div>
```

When we click on any li a filtering occurs based on the `data-filter` value and the div class value.

Say one li `data-filter` is ABC then when we click it all the divs under it that have class ABC will be shown, rest will be hidden. Am not sure how it works but it does work.

Now what I am trying to implement is to make the li(filters) and the divs dynamically bind using knockout. I was able to bind the lis' and divs but when i click the filter nothing is happening.

When I googled about isotope and knockout I found some issues due to conflicts (or not but that's what I understood). So do I have to do anything special to make it work?

This is the code i used to create the divs

```html
this is the knockout code i used to generate the divs `
<li class="mix color-1 TileItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-bind="visible: IsVisible, attr: { id: 'Report_' + ProductID + '_' + LinkID }">
  <div class="tileItem-Tab1 f1_card cbp-item-wrapper">
    <a class="tileImgPrnt cbp-caption cbp-lightbox" data-title="The Gang Blue<br>by Cosmin Capitanu">
      <div class="FltrTile_Img cbp-caption-defaultWrap" data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(' + LinkImage + ')' }"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="tileImg_Text" data-bind="text: LinkDefaultName"></div>
  </div>
</li>`
```

This is the code i used to create the filters

```html
Hi, this is the knockout code i used to generate the filter li `
<li class="placeholder">
  <input type="button" class="FltrBtn FltrBtn_active" data-bind="click: function () { filter(FilterLinkID, ProductID, this) }, value: FilterName, attr: { id: 'Filter_' + ProductID + '_' + FilterID }, css: { 'FltrBtn_active': $index() == 0 } " />
</li>`
```

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered. You should take some time to set up a complete, minimal sample that reproduces the problem you observe. The essential sentence in your post is *"I was able to bind the lis' and divs but when i click the filter nothing is happening."*, yet your question shows none of this.

Comment: Please edit your question directly instead of posting code to the comments. :) You can insert a live snippet of code (much like jsfiddle) directly into the question as well.

Comment: Hi Tomalak,
What i mean is that even though i was able to produce the same DOM as static using knockout , the filtering is not working.

Comment: I understand that, still without having actual code to work with, it's impossible for anyone to track down the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question with the knockout template

Comment: And now try to turn it into [a complete, working code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you noticed that the code editor has separate panes for HTML, JavaScript and CSS? Use them to put together a sample that actually shows what you currently have.

Comment: the dynamically binded data is from DB so pasting the script wont do good na?I can share the viewmodel of ko

Comment: You can use fake data that represents your real data. In the end, someone who is trying to help you would need that anyway, so not providing it is pretty counter-productive.

Comment: What is the plug-in you reference?

Comment: I have added isotope-custom.js & jquery.isotope.min.js . What if i create the control purely in JS will it work? Because i dont have that much knowledge in  KO and there is absolutely no time to finish it.